# Is there a way to stop Stream.iterate() with a predicate?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In the web I found only one way to stop the iterate method. By using the limit() function. But that iterates a concreate ammount of loops. I want  use for the halt a predicate.

```
...
Stream.iterate(0, i -> i*2).while(i -> i < MAX)
...
```

Is there a way to do it with Streams?

Update 1 : Java 8 is used

Comment: What you really want to achieve? What is your usecase?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I want to implement a Stream that calculates Fibbonacies that are smaller than a certain number

Comment: Show us your input and expected output. There may be better ways of doing this. People can't answer a question without knowing it's context properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Java-9 or above, one way is to use [`Stream.takeWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) as:

```
Stream.iterate(1, i -> i * 2) // notice identity value in seed
      .takeWhile(i -> i < MAX)
```

Another alternative is to use [`Stream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.function.UnaryOperator))

```
Stream.iterate(1, i -> i < MAX, i -> i * 2)
```

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that this was added in Java 9.

Comment: is there any alternate for Stream.iterate.takeWhile() in Java-8

Comment: Its a cool way to do it. Thanks. But I am using Java 8. I will update my question

Comment: The third parameter in `iterate` is not really an alternative to `takewhile`, though, as `takewhile` can e.g. be applied after a `map` step. Of course, for OP's case it may be fine.

Comment: @tobias_k well true, specific to dealing with integers currently. More likely towards the `IntStream` if I could say so.

Comment: Are there any differences, performance-wise, between the two approaches?